# Can I use jinja2 without a framework?

Tags: templates, jinja2

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to jinja2. Is it necessary to build in a framework to use jinja2? Ideally, I would use html, css, js, and jinja. And I suppose a python file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a framework with jinja2, only something that emits HTTP when you render the template.

Here's the general pattern for serving webpages without a framework:
[h/t for the Python 2 version](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997)

```
# import your jinja2 modules here
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self): # handle GET request
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(# call Jinja2 renderer here)

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=MyHandler, port=80):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print("Starting server...")
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Note where you call Jinja2 in this example, in the GET method of the request handler.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja is meant to be used for templating within python - if you're writing a basic web app with js, html, and css, you can use [es6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to template js values/variables in your html. If you're writing your frontend logic with js, this is probably what you're looking for.

However if you're more comfortable with Python, and are planning to write your app with Python instead, probably you'd want to go with a basic framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/) (and then yes, you'd be using jinja2).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Well, my main goal was to build a template for our own micro-site generator which doesn't allow for builds ie. why I can't use a framework. I was told to build this jinja but was unable to find ways I could use it without a framework.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Then I think @cowbert's answer below will help you